# Inno Setup: pack folder with all subfolders

Tags: inno-setup

I have this line in `.iss` file:

```
Source: "..\Tcl\*"; DestDir: "{app}\Tcl"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

which packs folder `Tcl`. But it takes only files inside folder, but does not take subfolders inside `Tcl`. Is there a way to take entire folder `Tcl` with all subfolders and files? (without listing all that subfolders line by line).

Inno Setup 5.4.2.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Yes, there is. Simply include the [`recursesubdirs`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_filessection.htm#recursesubdirs) flag to your `[Files]` section entry. The help says about this flag the following:

> Instructs the compiler or Setup to also search for the Source
>   filename/wildcard in subdirectories under the Source directory.

So, all you should do is modify your `[Files]` section entry this way:

```
[Files]
Source: "..\Tcl\*"; DestDir: "{app}\Tcl"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs
```

Comment: Would `Source: "..\Tcl"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs` work too?

Comment: @Septagram from trying it out myself it appears to result in a compilation error `..\Tcl not found`

Answer (score 28):

You can also use the Inno Wizard, but you'll need to correct the script afterwards if you would like those files to stay in the folder they're imported from, because the Wizard will put them in the app default folder.

The wizard wil generate:

```
 [Files]
 Source: "..\Tcl\*"; DestDir: "{app}; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs
```

If you need to maintain the folder structure you'll need:

```
 [Files]
 Source: "..\Tcl\*"; DestDir: "{app}\Tcl"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs
```

**Inno Wizard Update as of 5.6.1 (08/14/2018)**
The Inno Setup Script Wizard now has the option to specify a subfolder. On the *Application Files* step of the wizard, use the *Add Folder...* button, then after you select the folder you would like to add, make sure it is selected in the list and then click *Edit...* and under the *Destination Subfolder* textbox, specify where you would like the previously selected folder contents to go.

Comment: this saved me lot of time and frustration, tks!

Comment: wonder why this isn't the default behavior. this is so hard to debug when it happens with your apps

Comment: I'm confused as to why this isn't the default behavior. Regardless, thanks!